# Monotonic Clock in C

Tags: c, algorithm, time, clock

I'm doing a algorithm project for my University. In the project I have to write some algorithms and evaluate their time using a **monotonic** clock.

I've already implemented everything using C but now I'm facing problems with the time measuring.

I'm currently using `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, ...)` to get a clock. From the manpage of `clock_gettime`:

```
CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW (since Linux 2.6.28; Linux-specific)
              Similar to CLOCK_MONOTONIC, but provides access to a raw hardware-based time that is not subject to NTP adjustments
              or  the  incremental  adjustments  performed by adjtime(3).  This clock does not count time that the system is sus‐
              pended.
```

The problem is the following: this clock *sometimes* returns a negative value when a measure like this is done:

```
struct timespec start,end;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start);
do{
    // do stuff in here
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &end);
} while((double) (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) <= *a certain quantity needed for precision*);
```

In particular, sometimes `end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec` is negative and this causes the program to loop into this do-while.

As this ***should*** be a monotonic clock (which never goes back), things like having a negative elapsed time should not happen. But still, it seems to be happening.

Is this clock really monotonic? Am i doing something wrong? What can I try to figure out what is wrong?

I am really lost, I've tried lot of things in the past few days and none has worked out.
In the case that more code is needed, see my repo: https://github.com/AlessandroZanatta/AlgorithmsProject/blob/dev/first_part/times.c

Comment: what about overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `man timespec`

There is written:

> ```
> struct timespec {
>                     time_t          tv_sec;
>                     long            tv_nsec;
>             };
> ```
>
> The *tv_sec* member is again the elapsed time in whole seconds.
> The *tv_nsec* member represents the rest of the elapsed time in nanoseconds.

So `tv_nsec` is just the **rest** of the time not representable in whole seconds, so you need to subtract seconds and nanoseconds.

#### Subtracting timespecs

Also here https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.5/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html is presented "the best way" to subtract two values of type `struct timeval`, as follows:

(For `struct timespec` just substitute `timespec` for `timeval`, `tv_nsec` for `tv_usec` and `1000000000` for `1000000`.)

> It is often necessary to subtract two values of type struct timeval or struct timespec. Here is the best way to do this. It works even on some peculiar operating systems where the tv_sec member has an unsigned type.
>
> ```
> /* Subtract the `struct timeval' values X and Y,
>    storing the result in RESULT.
>    Return 1 if the difference is negative, otherwise 0.  */
>
> int
> timeval_subtract (result, x, y)
>      struct timeval *result, *x, *y;
> {
>   /* Perform the carry for the later subtraction by updating y. */
>   if (x->tv_usec < y->tv_usec) {
>     int nsec = (y->tv_usec - x->tv_usec) / 1000000 + 1;
>     y->tv_usec -= 1000000 * nsec;
>     y->tv_sec += nsec;
>   }
>   if (x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec > 1000000) {
>     int nsec = (x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec) / 1000000;
>     y->tv_usec += 1000000 * nsec;
>     y->tv_sec -= nsec;
>   }
>
>   /* Compute the time remaining to wait.
>      tv_usec is certainly positive. */
>   result->tv_sec = x->tv_sec - y->tv_sec;
>   result->tv_usec = x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec;
>
>   /* Return 1 if result is negative. */
>   return x->tv_sec < y->tv_sec;
> }
> ```

Comment: Can't believe I missed this... I'll try out, hope it works!

Comment: `int nsec` is a confusing name.  looks like it implies nanoseconds.  Perhaps `sec`?

Comment: actually I don't know why they chose `nsec` as the variable name. It is just the quoted code from the link above. And yes it is confusing. :-)